# Python pulp library - different outputs on Windows and Linux/Mac

Tags: python-3.x, pulp

I am facing issue with python pulp library in our production code when we deploy the code in Windows and Linux OS.

The issue is difference in objective value between the two OS.

As an example, I ran the test code from the below website tutorial using pulp 2.2:
https://benalexkeen.com/linear-programming-with-python-and-pulp-part-5/

In Windows system, the objective value output is **10980000**.
In Linux based system (Mac), the objective value output is **12906400**.

I have same python version on both systems and same pulp version (2.2).

Can anyone please suggest why this can be the case? Is there a known bug?

**Edit** (Code which I ran - provided on tutorial site):

```
import pandas as pd
import pulp

factories = pd.read_csv('factory_variables.csv', index_col=['Month', 'Factory'])
demand = pd.read_csv('monthly_demand.csv', index_col=['Month'])
production = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("production",
                                     ((month, factory) for month, factory in factories.index),
                                     lowBound=0,
                                     cat='Integer')
factory_status = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("factory_status",
                                     ((month, factory) for month, factory in factories.index),
                                     cat='Binary')
model = pulp.LpProblem("Cost minimising scheduling problem", pulp.LpMinimize)
model += pulp.lpSum(
    [production[month, factory] * factories.loc[(month, factory), 'Variable_Costs'] for month, factory in factories.index]
    + [factory_status[month, factory] * factories.loc[(month, factory), 'Fixed_Costs'] for month, factory in factories.index]
)

# Production in any month must be equal to demand
months = demand.index
for month in months:
    model += production[(month, 'A')] + production[(month, 'B')] == demand.loc[month, 'Demand']

# Production in any month must be between minimum and maximum capacity, or zero.
for month, factory in factories.index:
    min_production = factories.loc[(month, factory), 'Min_Capacity']
    max_production = factories.loc[(month, factory), 'Max_Capacity']
    model += production[(month, factory)] >= min_production * factory_status[month, factory]
    model += production[(month, factory)] <= max_production * factory_status[month, factory]

# Factory B is off in May
model += factory_status[5, 'B'] == 0
model += production[5, 'B'] == 0
solver = pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(keepFiles=True)
model.solve(solver)
pulp.LpStatus[model.status]
```

Also, please find csv files on this link: https://github.com/benalexkeen/Introduction-to-linear-programming/tree/master/csv

Comment: While slight differences are expected (e.g. objective-deviation of `10^-7`), this does not sound right. Double-check everything a-priori cbc-solving! E.g. writing out the LP-file and hashing it, diffing it (with some difftool) and so on. If needed, even cross-solve the LP-files (windows-produced .lp with linux-based cbc executable). Lots of possible forensic work. My guess: the problem is not to be found in pulp or it's solver. Even a different pandas-version with some `read_csv` changes could be responsible. (and non type-safe stuff like csv is always a pain: e.g. EU vs. US decimals-char...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All library versions are same, we even checked all the inputs prior to prob.solver() and then used same solver on both windows/linux. I finally used some examples like the above tutorial and ran it on the two OS, the answer was different.

Comment: Then prepare a reproducible example (no: no puzzle it together from this link). The tutorial code looks trivial (without numerical issues) and people could quickly confirm or even debug this if it would be reproducible.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the code and added the link for the csv files.

Comment: I tried the code in both Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. It gave the same result: objective function=12906400.

Comment: Macos also gives 12906400

Comment: @pchtsp I tried running code on Windows 2012 server and thats the result I got and it was exact same code. Did you do anything different on Windows to get same result?

Comment: @user5711693 I did not change anything. Maybe try downloading the files again to the server? they may not be the exact ones you have in the server...